# repeating rows of data based on specific data in a given group of cells

Tags: excel

I have a row of data that contains 40 possible cells of specific data that I need to separate and repeat that row of data with the cell that contains the specific data out the 40 possibilities and then continue to repeat this process until there are no more cells with the specific data.

EqType1 and EqSerial1 would need to be selected together but are in separate cells.  this example should return 2 rows of data the first with the FirstName LastName EqType1 EqSerial1 and the second row with FirstName LastName EqType2 EqSerial2 and then stop if there are no more Eq and move on to the next row of data and perform the same function over again.

Sample Row of Data:

```
FirstName   LastName    EqType1   EqSerial1      EqType2    EqSerial2
MORGAN      TURNBULL    ARPCXDT   PAX501037020   TG1682G    7823AE179414
```

Comment: Doesn't really matter if you are new at this; what matters is that you can show your original effort at resolving the problem and explain why it isn't working the way you want it to. This is what you agreed to when you joined this community.

Comment: in addition to what @Jeeped said, the question doesn't really make sense. we need some sort of sample desired output.

Answer (score 0):

> "this example should return 2 rows of data the first with the FirstName LastName EqType1 EqSerial1 and the second row with FirstName LastName EqType2 EqSerial2"

***A disclaimer:*** The following will only work if you put your 2 new combined indexes into columns and not rows

If I understand your question correctly, you could try this:

- Insert two extra columns at the end of your data: `Eq1` and `Eq2`

So your data would be laid out like this:

```
  A         B        C       D            E       F            G    H
1 FirstName LastName EqType1 EqSerial1    EqType2 EqSerial2    Eq1 Eq2
2 MORGAN    TURNBULL ARPCXDT PAX501037020 TG1682G 7823AE179414
```

- In cell G2 insert the formula: `= A2 & " " & B2 & " " & C2 & " " & D2`
- In cell H2 insert the formula: `= A2 & " " & B2 & " " & E2 & " " & F2`